# Using old version of GWT SDK with Eclipse Luna

Tags: eclipse, gwt, google-plugin-eclipse

we have a project which is compatible with GWT SDK 2.4 and Eclipse Indigo. I am trying to move to Eclipse Luna. Although I have made a progress, I couldn't get all of the features yet. Here is what I've done:

- Downloaded Eclipse Luna and JDK 1.7 (both 64 bit)
- Using install new software, installed last version of GWT SDK and
  designer
- Downloaded GWT SDK 2.4
- Set this SDK as default (I copied some jars from SDK 2.6 in order to
  do this)

After this installation, the project succesfully compiled and debugged. In addition, there are no problems with GWT Designer with my old ui.xml files. However, when I try to add new page I realized that Add New MVP view is gone. Is there a way to bring back this feature? Or can I copy from old Eclipse plugins?

Comment: I guess you already know that but : from 2.7 release note "GWT Designer doesn’t work with 2.7 and is no longer supported." So I guess you are going to have a hard time finding someone to help you.

Comment: Why do you want download latest gwt sdk and then again gwt sdk 2.4.... You can just add gwt sdk 2.4 as a dependency or set it default. I guess somewhere both the versions are getting mixed up